# Access props outside class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using `react-bootstrap-table` with `cellEdit` enabled. It is possible to use a callback function in `react-bootstrap-table` after the cell has been edited. I've named the callback function `onAfterSaveCell`. The updated row in table will be saved to a variable called `row`. I would like to send `row` to an action creator called `pushData` that accepts `row` as an input. My code looks like this.

```
function onAfterSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue){
  this.props.pushData(row);
} 

const cellEditProp = {
  mode: "click",
  blurToSave: true,
  afterSaveCell: onAfterSaveCell
};

class Feature extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMessage();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.message) return null

    return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable
              data={this.props.message}
              cellEdit={cellEditProp}
              >
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="ccyCode" isKey={true} dataSort={true}>Valutakod</TableHeaderColumn>......
```

When I run the code I the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`. Which I think is due to that `props` is not available outside the `class Feature`. I've tried to move in the `onAfterSaveCell` function and `cellEditProp` in to `class Feature` but this give me a compilation error. How can I make `props` accessible outside the `class Feature` or should this be solved in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you cannot use the `this` keyword outside the class. So the obvious answer is to define your callback-function inside the class. I think the reason you got a compilation error is due to a syntax error, since this should work just fine:

```
class Feature extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.onAfterSaveCell = this.onAfterSaveCell.bind(this); // important!
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMessage();
  }

  onAfterSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue) {
    this.props.pushData(row);
  }



  render() {
    if (!this.props.message) return null

    return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable
              data={this.props.message}
              cellEdit={{
                mode: "click",
                blurToSave: true,
                afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell
                }}
              >
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="ccyCode" isKey={true} dataSort={true}>Valutakod</TableHeaderColumn>......
```